# Resolution - what about the same variables in different formulas?

Tags: logic

$$\begin{array}{l:l}
  (1) & \forall x~\exists y~\big(R(x,y) \lor S(x,y)\big) 
\\(2) & \exists x~\forall y~\big(R(x,y) ~\to~ S(x,y) \land T(x)\big) 
\\(3) & \forall x~\Big(\exists y~\big(S(x,y) \land \neg R(x,y)\big)~\to~T(x)\Big)
\\(4) & \exists x~\exists y~\big(S(x,y)\land T(x)\big) \end{array}$$
Using resolution method prove that $(1)\land (2) \land (3) \Rightarrow (4)$.   I know, that we should try to get contradiction of $(1)\land (2) \land (3) \land \neg (4)$ and get for each formula CNF form.   However, I don't know what we should with variables - exactly I don't know if I should rename variables in separate formulas ?  for example we have $x$ in every of formula.

**Edit**
For second:
$$R(V, y) \Rightarrow S(V,y)\land T(V)$$
For fourth $$(S(A, B)\land T(A)$$

How to finish this resolution ?

Comment: For (4): NO; we need the *negation* of the conclusion (as you said): $\lnot ∃x ∃y (S(x,y)∧T(x))$ i.e. the *clause* $\lnot S(x,y) \lor \lnot T(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the variables will be "handled" successively by [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)).

The first step is to transform the formulae in CNF form and then "skolemize" them, removing the quantifiers, like for (1):

> (1) $ \ \ R(x,f(x)) ∨ S(x,f(x))$.

Of course, different occurrences of existential quantifiers need different skolem functions (or constatnts).

Thus, for (3) we will have:

> $¬S(x,g(x)) ∨ R(x,g(x)) ∨ T(x)$.

Comment: Could you again glance to my post ? (I edited it)

Comment: Could you look here ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807548/proving-implications-by-resolution